# Is Amazon DynamoDB slower than Amazon RDS (php)?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-dynamodb

We use a bunch of AWS services hosted in the Singapore region. We have a few EC2 instances and an RDS instance. We were planning to migrate some of our data to Amazon DynamoDB, which will help in our application data design.

Unfortunately, DynamoDB is always slower than RDS. I have written a single row in a table created in the same region as our EC2 instances. Reading this row takes more than 1 second using the AmazonAWS SDK for php, and fetching a row from RDS using mysql takes more than 10 times lesser than that.

Is there something we can do to optimize this? I have disabled SSL, but I don't think it made much of a difference.

Comment: You can always answer your own question :-) thanks for the up-vote.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly. DynamoDB has considerable latency and runs on top of a thicker application stack than does a RDS hosted database (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle).

However, IMO the key advantage of DynamoDB (and most NoSQL dbs) is that the latency is dependable. If you are seeing a 400 ms latency on record retrieval, you can count on that 400 ms latency with 1 session or with 100,000 sessions.

[Note: 1 second does seem like a long time - we able to get multiple records < second in most instances, but I've not really used the DynamoDB method for the PHP specific SDK (just .Net). I wonder if something else could be bottle-necking.]

Comment: Yes, I get that the strong point of DynamoDB is reliability when it comes to larger data sets and more connections. But I'd be very happy with 400ms, even though it is still quite a bit slower than MySQL on RDS. My 1 second delay is unbearable. I used the scan api call to fetch a record based on a string comparison. That took one second. Are you saying that this is faster on the .net drivers?

Comment: @Munim I wouldn't assume that the .net drivers would be any faster (or not enough to be of concern). I just don't have a point of reference as I haven't used the php SDK for dynamoDB. My hunch is they would be nearly the same as *most* of the processing should be done on the service.

How many records are you scanning? Anytime you can query on hash-range, you should be orders of magnitude faster than a scan.

Comment: I've been trying scan and get_items on hash-ranges and they are all slow. I just have one record in the table to test for now.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your previous comment I'd say that scan is your problem. You really only want to be using that when absolutely essential, i.e. to feed data into map reduce for analytics or something along those lines. As far as I'm aware, scan actually goes through every single record and looks for items matching your criteria (sloooowwwww), where as get/query works off the nicely indexed hash/range keys.

If possible you should be structuring your data so that you can query off of the hash/range key, If that's not feasible you could look at putting your meta data / query fields into cloudsearch, using that to return the id then directly getting the item from Dynamo. You could also set up some denomalized tables (restructuring the same data in different tables so you have different range keys)

You shouldn't see those large latency times with get and query commands using the PHP SDK.

Comment: Hmm.. Can I pick up an item from the second range key alone without specifying the hash key? I still not very familiar with that concept of the hash/range keys. I think using cloudsearch will just another additional request overhead, and I'd possibly try to avoid that. I hadn't thought of denomalizing. That is an interesting idea.

Comment: Actually, no. I tried using a simple getitem call. It is still fairly slow (> 1 second).

Comment: @Munim - if getitem is slow, there must be another problem.

Comment: @Hal I have been doing some more digging and object creation itself is taking up a long time, compared to the actual querying. I think something is wrong with the APC caching. Digging in more..

Comment: @Hal yep, my hunch was right! Using filesystem caching sped it up very quickly. I have to fix my APC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DynamoDB with the AWS SDK for PHP, you should make sure stay up-to-date with which version of the SDK you are using. Specifically, you need to be using version 1.5.9+ in order to get the best performance for DynamoDB operations. There were some issues resolved recently that were adding extra latency to some requests, so this may help you out a lot.

Also, DynamoDB recently add support for AWS SignatureV4 for signing requests, which removes the need for STS credentials which the SDK previously retrieved and cached for you. This should also contribute to better performance as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have solved most of the latency issues by fixing caching on my server, but I will look into the newer version of the library too.